# Highcharts Highmaps plugin legend bug

Tags: highcharts

We have highcharts implemented on our web sites and have recently come across the HighMaps Beta plugin which is awesome!!

My problem comes about when I attempt to attach a legend to the HighMap.
  - It turns the US map completely BLACK and does not color the states appropriately.  However if you hover over the states the information is present.
  - See jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bSTB5/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/maps/us.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

```
$(function () {

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=us-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    // Instanciate the map
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        chart : {
            borderWidth : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'US population density (/km²)'
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 1,
            type: 'logarithmic',
            minColor: '#EEEEFF',
            maxColor: '#000022',
            stops: [
                [0, '#EFEFFF'],
                [0.67, '#4444FF'],
                [1, '#000022']
            ]
        },

        series : [{
            animation: true,
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps.us,
            joinBy: 'code',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'white',
                format: '{point.code}',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black',
                    textTransform: 'uppercase'
                }
            },
            name: 'Population density',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.value}/km²'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

If I disable the legend:  "{enabled: false"}" then suddenly the US States are colored correctly but I have no legend of course.
jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmnC3/

This is my current demo to my client.

Note that it only does it when I attempt to include the js files as stated in the "HighMaps Startup Guide" which states the following:

*"If you already have Highcharts installed in the web page and want to run Highmaps as a plugin, include this script tag after highcharts.js:

"*

If I use the HighMap include files like in this jFiddle everything works great.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/color-axis/

The only problem is I cannot do this type of include in my aspx page due to the fact that some of my clients do not have a HighMap chart and if I only show a HighChart with this include then all the HighCharts stop working...

Our page has multiple clients (some have just highcharts and some have highcharts AND a highmap demo)

Anyone seen this and know how to fix it?
Is it a known bug?
Lastly, does anyone know a date for the release of HighMaps?

Our clients are eager to have it in full action!

Thanks
Lance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug when using Highcharts 4.x with Highmaps 1.x. Right now use Highcharts 3.x instead. See: http://jsfiddle.net/zmnC3/1/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/3.0/highcharts.js"></script>
```